# Что значит size_t index(0);?

Tags: c++, переменные, c++14, инициализация

Что значит [`size_t index(0);`](https://github.com/njuzpw/Boyer-Moore/blob/master/bm.cpp)?

Причем не совсем понятно именно здесь `(0);

Эквивалентно ли это записи `size_t index = 0;` или есть нюансы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто определение переменной `index` типа `size_t`, инициализированной значением 0...

Эквивалентно

```
size_t index = 0;
size_t index{0};
```

и даже

```
size_t index{};
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо